# an exponential sum involving quadratics

Tags: number-theory, exponential-sum

Let $q$ be a prime and $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Can we compute $$\sum_{k=1}^{q}e^{2\pi i\frac{ak^2+bk}{q}}$$ in terms of $a,b,q$? The sum is easy when $a=0$, but what about the case $a\neq 0$?

Comment: [Generalized Quadratic Gaussian Sum wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#Generalized_quadratic_Gauss_sums)

Comment: Complete the square and look up [Gauss' sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum). Yours is the case Wikipedia refers to as quadratic Gauss' sum. Ireland & Rosen has more details.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Let me rephrase your idea. The case $b=0$ is known, so we want to reduce the matter to this case. Since we are working on the field $\mathbb{Z}_q$, we can do all the +,-*,/. Write $ak^2+bk=a(k+l)^2+c$ for some $l$ and $c$. By a change of variable, we can drop $l$. $c$ depends on both $a$ and $b$. So we can see that $b$ only contributes to a modulation and it does not affect the magnitude. Am I correct?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen BTW, to be precise $c=-\frac{b^2}{4a}$. Here $\frac{1}{4a}$ means the multiplicative inverse of $4a$ in the filed $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Comment: That's the idea, Dony.

Comment: @r9m In this wiki page, there is a formula $g(a;p)=(\frac{a}{p})g(1;p)$. But when a=0, LHS=p but RHS=0.